# Word 2010 template not acting as template -- saving over .dotx file!

Tags: microsoft-word, templates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you make changes to a Word template?](https://superuser.com/questions/239340/how-do-you-make-changes-to-a-word-template)

I have a Word 2010 file that I save as a .dotx file, a Word template. My understanding is that when I open this file and make changes, I can't save over it; I have to pick a new file name that's defaulted to the .docx extension. However when I chose 'Save' it saves over the .dotx original, and when I choose "save as", it defaults to saving over the .dotx again. In other words, it acts just like a regular docx file and not a template :P

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

This depends on how you open the .dotx file.

If you open it by double clicking, it should give you a new document based on this template, which tries to save as a .docx file. This works the same when within Word, you click the round button and choose 'new'. In the dialog, choose 'new from existing'.

If you right click -> 'open' to open the .dotx file, then it will open the template for revision. The same happens when you open the .dotx through the round office button (forgot the name) and choose 'open'.

Answer (score 3):

If you open the .dotx, then you're editing the template, so it will save as a template (otherwise how do you maintain the template. Don't you need to create a new .docx based on the template (via File|New), that then gives you a new document that will save as you require.